# Wordpress - multi site subdomain showing iframe in place of html

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress Site, I have a subdomain m.example.com which is pointing to same folder where main website is running example.com. But I am unable to view html code in source. And if i do redirect after detecting Mobile screen to m.example.com, Responsive is not working, but it working fine on main domain.

Below is the code showing in subdomain website..`<html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>m.example.com</title>
                <meta name="description" content="m.example.com" />
                <meta name="keywords" content="" />
                <style>html{overflow-x: auto;}</style>
            </head>
            <frameset rows="*,0%" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
                <frame src="http://www.example.com" frameborder="0" resizable="no">
                <frame frameborder="0">
            </frameset>
        </html>`

Answer (score -2):

```
Redirect sub domain to your main site folder from cpanel manage sub domains option. Avoid to use frameset.
```

Comment: Same thing I have did.

Comment: @Rahul Please provide examples or code with your answer. Simply wrapping your answer in a code tag is just cheating the system and does not help anyone.